# How can I add breadcrumbs in content CMS page from backoffice Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, breadcrumbs

I have already tried this solution but with no result! I want to display image then breadcrumbs and finally a paragraph

```
[{block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not posssible from admin please add this code in **cms_page_view_id_{IDENTIFIER}.xml**

and add below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="breadcrumbs" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```